# how can i block some parts of an url while using php cURL?

Tags: php, curl

because of bandwith problem, i'd like to block all images while using cURL on a remote url. Let me give a quick example: A page has 200 jpg images, i wanna get that page without 200 images with cURL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When cURLing a URL, you're only receiving what is at that URL, which is likely just an HTML document.
cURL does **not** automatically download all 200 images that are referred to in the HTML document, because cURL does not care about HTML. Quite the contrary; if you *wanted* to download all 200 images, you'd have to parse the HTML by hand and make further cURL request for each individual image.

Example from the command line:

```
$ curl -i www.w3.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 02:46:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Content-Location: Home.html
Vary: negotiate,accept,Accept-Encoding
TCN: choice
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Feb 2011 20:42:28 GMT
ETag: "74f2-49b3e92157500;89-3f26bd17a2f00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 29938
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Expires: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 02:56:36 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://www.w3.org/2001/05/P3P/p3p.xml"
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<!-- Generated from data/head-home.php, ../../smarty/{head.tpl} -->
<head>
<title>World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="Help" href="/Help/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/2008/site/css/minimum" type="text/css" media="handheld, all" />
<style type="text/css" media="print, screen and (min-width: 481px)">
/*<![CDATA[*/
@import url("/2008/site/css/advanced");
/*]]>*/
</style>
<link href="/2008/site/css/minimum" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/2008/site/css/print" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/2008/site/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="description" content="The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) is an international community where Member organizations, a full-time staff, and the public work together to develop Web standards." />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="W3C News" href="/News/atom.xml" />
</head>
<body id="www-w3-org" class="w3c_public w3c_home">
<div id="w3c_container">
<!-- Generated from data/mast-home.php, ../../smarty/{mast.tpl} -->
<div id="w3c_mast"><!-- #w3c_mast / Page top header -->
<h1 class="logo"><a tabindex="2" accesskey="1" href="/"><img src="/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" width="90" height="53" alt="W3C" /></a> <span class="alt-logo">W3C</span></h1>
<div id="w3c_nav">

...
```

That's all a cURL request gets. There's one image in there: `<img src="/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" width="90" height="53" alt="W3C" />`. That's all you're getting of it, you're not getting the image itself.

Comment: i dont wanna download 200 images. i wanna block them.

Comment: @wild Again, cURL **won't** download images referred to in an HTML document. To cURL it's all just text, it doesn't *read* the text. As such, you don't need to do anything, because the images won't be downloaded automatically.

Comment: you aren't actually downloading the images in a curl request. Are you talking about removing them from the curl response text because you are then outputting the results of the curl request?

Comment: cURL gets images. cURL gets all page.

Comment: @wild If you're just referring to wanting to download the HTML without the image **tags** inside the HTML, then you're out of luck. You can't ask the server "please send me the page without the image tags" and you can't filter the tags without first downloading them.

Comment: sorry, you can't do that.  The curl request will return what is normally output to a browser (like rightclick > view source).  So the image tags will be there and there is nothing you can do to make the actual request not include it. But you aren't actually downloading the images at that point, just the source code, so just the image tags.

Comment: @wild Again, if the server doesn't offer a version of the HTML without image tags, that's not possible. If you know exactly at which byte offset these tags start, it may be possible, but I doubt that's the case. Are 200 small `<img>` tags that much of a bandwidth problem? The images itself I can understand, but just the tags...?

Comment: im publishing page. i use echo for publishing page to the screen. so, 200 images are showing up

Comment: @wild If you're outputting the result to a browser, then **the browser** will read and interpret the HTML, and of course it will download the images. cURL itself does **not** download the images. Test it. Write the results to a file and open the file in a text editor. No images in there, only HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it without the images but you can strip them from the results easy enough with regex or a dom parser...but with curl, you aren't actually making a request for the images, just the html on the page (so you'd be stripping out the tags)